# I am trying to create a post in instagram clone in ruby and rails but it throws an error "no implicit conversion of Integer into string"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is the Post Model

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord

    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
    scope :active, -> { where active: true }
end
```

This is the Post Controlller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @post = Post.new
    end

    def create
        @post = Post.new(post_params)

        if @post.save
            redirect_to dashboard_path, flash: { success: "Post Created Successfuly" }
        else
            redirect_to new_post_path, flash: { danger: "Post was not saved Successfuly" }
        end
    end

    def show
    end

    private
    
    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:image, :image_cache)
    end

end
```

This the Database Table for create post

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
    def change
        create_table :posts do |t|
            t.string :image
            t.boolean :active
            t.references :account
            t.timestamps
        end
    end
end
```

This the Request created when save post

```
Parameters:
{"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "post"=>
  {"image"=>
    #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007fc4a96c25a8
     @content_type="image/png",
     @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"post[image]\"; filename=\"image(2).png\"\r\n" + "Content-Type: image/png\r\n",
     @original_filename="image(2).png",
     @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20220421-27384-m946e8.png>>,
   "image_cache"=>""},
```

This is the Form to create post on front end

```
<%= form_for @post, html: { multipart: true } do |f|%>
<%= f.file_field :image, class: "form-control" %>
<%= f.hidden_field :image_cache %>
<%= f.submit "Save Post", class: "btn btn-success"%>
<% end %>
```

TypeError in PostsController#create
no implicit conversion of Integer into String

```
def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params) // This line have error

    if @post.save
        redirect_to dashboard_path, flash: { success: "Post Created Successfuly" }
```

Backtrace

```
["/home/hexcoder/Desktop/instagram-clone/app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:8:in `backtrace'", 
"/home/hexcoder/Desktop/instagram-clone/app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:8:in `create'", 
"/home/hexcoder/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/web-console-4.2.0/lib/web_console/evaluator.rb:24:in `eval'", 
"/home/hexcoder/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/web-console-4.2.0/lib/web_console/evaluator.rb:24:in `eval'", 
"/home/hexcoder/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/web-console-4.2.0/lib/web_console/session.rb:57:in `eval'", 
"/home/hexcoder/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/web-console-4.2.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:104:in `block in update_repl_session'", 
"/home/hexcoder/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/web-console-4.2.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:69:in `block in json_response_with_session'",
"/home/hexcoder/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/web-console-4.2.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:61:in `json_response'", 
"/home/hexcoder/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/web-console-4.2.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:69:in `json_response_with_session'", 
"/home/hexcoder/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/web-console-4.2.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:102:in `update_repl_session'", 
"/home/hexcoder/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/web-console-4.2.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:22:in `block in call'", 
"/home/hexcoder/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/web-console-4.2.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `catch'", 
"/home/hexcoder/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/web-console-4.2.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `call'", 
"/home/hexcoder/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:26:in `call'", 
"/home/hexcoder/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'", 
"/home/hexcoder/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:25:in `block in call'", 
"/home/hexcoder/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `block in tagged'", 
"/home/hexcoder/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:37:in `tagged'", 
"/home/hexcoder/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `tagged'", 
"/home/hexcoder/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:25:in `call'", 
"/home/hexcoder/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.4.2/lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'", 
"/home/hexcoder/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:93:in `call'", 
"/home/hexcoder/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:26:in `call'", 
"/home/hexcoder/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'", 
"/home/hexcoder/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'", 
"/home/hexcoder/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.2.3/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'", 
"/home/hexcoder/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/server_timing.rb:20:in `call'", 
"/home/hexcoder/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'", 
"/home/hexcoder/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:23:in `call'", 
"/home/hexcoder/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'", 
"/home/hexcoder/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:137:in `call'", 
"/home/hexcoder/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:530:in `call'", 
"/home/hexcoder/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/puma-5.6.4/lib/puma/configuration.rb:252:in `call'", 
"/home/hexcoder/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/puma-5.6.4/lib/puma/request.rb:77:in `block in handle_request'", 
"/home/hexcoder/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/puma-5.6.4/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:340:in `with_force_shutdown'", 
"/home/hexcoder/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/puma-5.6.4/lib/puma/request.rb:76:in `handle_request'", 
"/home/hexcoder/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/puma-5.6.4/lib/puma/server.rb:441:in `process_client'", 
"/home/hexcoder/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/puma-5.6.4/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:147:in `block in spawn_thread'"]
```

It will be very helpful if someone could answer this question and tell me where i am doing something wrong.

Comment: What is the full error? There should be a stack trace with the exception.

Comment: @muistooshort i have added the backtrace

Answer (score 0):

Your `Post` is supposed to be linked to an `Account`

```
create_table :posts do |t|
  #...
  t.references :account
  # ..
end
```

I would say there is an error during the `save` because `account_id` is `nil` or `empty`. It's the biggest mistake I see here.